# Access arraylist from a recycleradapter class

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to access an `ArrayList` from a nonactivity class to a fragment.

```
       @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final DataObjectHolder holder, final int position)
{
    holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
    holder.itemid.setText(mDataset.get(position).getItem_id());
    holder.itemname.setText(mDataset.get(position).getItem_name());
    holder.qty.setText(mDataset.get(position).getQty());
    int  rt=Integer.parseInt(mDataset.get(position).getRate().substring(0,mDataset.get(position).getRate().length() - 3));
    holder.rate.setText(formatter.format(rt)+".00");
    ItemDetails listItem = filterList.get(position);
    holder.itemname.setText(listItem.getItem_name());
    holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(++qt));
            mDataset.get(position).setQty(String.valueOf(qt));
            finalDataset.add(new ItemDetails(ItemFragment.getInstance().cat_id,String.valueOf(holder.itemid.getText()),String.valueOf(holder.itemname.getText()),String.valueOf(holder.rate.getText()),String.valueOf(holder.qty.getText())));
        }
    });
    holder.minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(qt==0)
            {
                holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(0));
            }
            else
            {
                holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(--qt));
            }
            mDataset.get(position).setQty(String.valueOf(qt));
            finalDataset.add(new ItemDetails(ItemFragment.getInstance().cat_id,String.valueOf(holder.itemid.getText()),String.valueOf(holder.itemname.getText()),String.valueOf(holder.rate.getText()),String.valueOf(holder.qty.getText())));
        }
    });
}
```

`finalDataset` is the mentioned `ArrayList`. I added the values to the `ArrayList` inside the `onBindViewHolder` method in `recycleradapter` class. And I want to access it in another fragment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create method to return List in adapter class,

```
public List<ItemDetails> getDataset() {
        return finalDataset;
}
```

In fragment class access it using,

```
List<ItemDetails> finalDataset = adapter.getDataset();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Please up-vote this answer, If helped. Happy Coding!